# PDO Exception error whenever I try to connecto to PostgreSQL database in PHP archive

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, loading

I am trying to make a data loading script to a series of models in a PostgreSQL  database. The problem is that I've been having this PDO Exception indicating that couldn't find drivers in the absolute path in which my PHP archive is.

I've looked up and this a fairly recurrent problem so there are things that I have tried:
First of all I downloaded  the VS16 x86 Thread Safe (2023-Oct-24 21:55:38) 8.2 PHP package from the PHP Downloads page. I installed as usual. In my /php directory (the one that has all of the data that comes from the download and you pase into your :C disk) I only have a php.ini-development archvie. As far as I understand this archive serves as a model for a php.ini archive or something like that.

That said, yes, I have tried both uncommenting the "extensions=pgsql" and "extensions=pdo_pgsql" lines from the php.ini-development archive and creating a php.ini archive with said lines and renaming the php.ini-development archive to php.ini with the uncommented lines. I have stated in all of those archives the absolute path for the extensions and nothing has worked, I still get the same damn exception message. I thought I was maybe due to the database so I switched to a new one that I locally created, with a new user with total access/permissions and still got the same problem.

This is keeping me from continuing working on the loading scripts. I don't know what else to do since theres little information on this exception online.

PS: I am using Windows.

Comment: When you install PHP on Windows, the installer might have put a `php.ini` file in your Windows folder. If you make a PHP file with `phpinfo()` in it and open it in your browser, you should get a page that tells you all sorts of things about your PHP configuration, including which `.ini` file(s) are loaded (and whether Postgres is available). Are there any ini-files listed there that you can edit to enable the extensions?

Comment: There is not much use of editing PHP archives locally when you need a running install. For a running version of PHP itself, all PHP extensions and all PHP scripts, they must be in non-archive form, e.g. plain files and not being an archive. Editing the archives or files within the archives are irrelevant for running PHP. Ensure you're following the instructions on installing PHP for your operating system. By writing archive did you mean file?

Comment: @rickdenhaan: I checked and there is no reference to any php.ini file.

Comment: @hakre: yes I meant file. I followed tutorials for installing PHP, and in all of them you just had to extract the downloaded zip files into a folder in the C:  or C:\Programs File directory.  in every other posts addressing this problem they solved it by editing the php.ini file as I said.

Comment: what is the full message of exception ? you went good path, there are two php.ini files one for production and one for development and you are supposed to rename one of them to just php.ini based on the environment you will use that installation. do you run your scripts as CLI or as server ? in case of server you need to restart that server to reread the php.ini config. btw `phpinfo()` provide list of loaded extensions, you should take a look at that too.